# Why am I not able to access the KeyCode member of System.EventArgs?

Tags: c#, .net

What am I doing wrong? Here is the error code that I get:

> 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'KeyCode' and no extension method 'KeyCode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BroZer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Reload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Refresh();
        }

        private void Go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void Back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoBack();
        }

        private void Forward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoForward();
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?&ie=UTF-8&q=" + textBox1.Text);
            }
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog();
        }

        private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Update: I figured it out. All you have to do is change

```
(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

to

```
(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 2):

To maximize your IDE use (i.e. Visual Studio), type this: textBox1.KeyDown += <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

It will give you the exact signature of the event's delegated method definition.

---

If your KeyDown's code is very trivial and you don't want to put it on separate method, you can opt to inline the code, i.e. you can embed the code in lambda:

```
textBox1.KeyDown += (s,e) => 
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
        webBrowser1.Navigate(
            "https://www.google.com/search?&ie=UTF-8&q=" + textBox1.Text);
```

Auto-complete still applies with lambda, i.e. when you type this: `if (e.`, the `KeyCode` will appear on auto-complete's dropdown list. With lambda, you don't need to know the exact signature of the delegated method.

Answer (score 0):

To assign `KeyDown` event of `textBox1` to `textBox1_KeyDown`, in design mode click on text box and look in *properties* window and click on *events* button and look for *keydown* and double click on it.[image]